# Getting an "React.createElement: type is invalid " warning when importing an exported const

Tags: reactjs

I have the following `const` that i'm exporting:

```
export const validator = (param) => (text) => {
...
...
}

const User = ({
    param1,
    param2
}) => (
    <Comp param1={param1} param2={param2} />
)

export default User;
```

And i'm importing it like this, to use in a unit test with Jest and Enzyme:

```
import User from '../User';
...
...
describe('<User />', () => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeAll(() => {
        wrapper = shallow(<User />);
    });
...
...
```

But i'm getting this warning when i run the test:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
>   default and named imports.

Why? Is that not the way to import this component?

Comment: How that `User` folder structure looks like?

Comment: You mean the folder `User` is in? It has about 10 other .JS component files.

Comment: yeah cuz in order to use `import User from '../User';` your file should look like this `User/index.js`

Comment: So given how the file is right now, how can i import it?

Comment: Can you post the whole component?

Comment: @ChrisB. i edited my post to include more details.